# mySQL select with PHP - left join

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables 'all' and 'jdetails'.  I have an existing select query on the all table which works.  I want to add some additional data from jdetails table if available.

all table:

```
judge, year, ...

jane doe, 2012

john doe, 2011
```

jdetails table:

```
name, designation,...

jane doe, level 1

jane doe, level 5

john doe, special
```

How do I change my query below to include the 'designation's (from jdetails) for each judge (in all)?

I think a left join is the solution but I have the where clause to consider.  Also, I absolutely must have the results of this query below, but with added data from jdetails table if it exists.

Additionally, there can be multiple rows (jdetails.name) of designations for each all.judge  which I want listed as a single value.  e.g.-- jane doe would have designation value of 'level 1 level 5'.

I would join on all.judge=jdetails.name

current query:

```
$rows = $my->get_row("SELECT all.judge, `year`, `totlevel_avg`, `totlevel_count`,   `genrank`, `poprank`, `tlevel_avg`, `tlevel_count`, `1level_avg` as `onelevel_avg`, `1level_count` as `onelevel_count`, `2level_avg` as `twolevel_avg`, `2level_count` as `twolevel_count`, `3level_avg` as `threelevel_avg`, `3level_count` as `threelevel_count`, `4level_avg` as `fourlevel_avg`, `4level_count` as `fourlevel_count`, `PSGlevel_avg`, `PSGlevel_count`, `I1level_avg`, `I1level_count`, `I2level_avg`, `I2level_count`, `GPlevel_avg`, `GPlevel_count`, `states` from `all` where `id` ='{$term}'");
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not include everything you had in your `SELECT` statement, I just summarized it with `ams.*`.  But the following links the `all` table to the `jdetails` table and then groups the designation into one field.  Then I wrap the results in an outer query that pulls the rest of the fields you need in the `all` table ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7eacc/2/0)):

```
SELECT ams.*, am.Desigs
FROM 
(
  SELECT a.judge, GROUP_CONCAT(j.designation SEPARATOR ', ') AS Desigs
  FROM `all` AS a
  INNER JOIN jdetails AS j ON a.judge = j.name
  GROUP BY a.judge
) AS am 
INNER JOIN `all` AS ams ON am.judge = ams.judge
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can help you:

```
`SELECT table1.column_name(s),table2.column_name(s) FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
 AND table1.column_name='Parameter'`
```

Where table 1 is all and table 2 is jdetails